# Gluster with s3ql mounted brick?

Tags: mount, amazon-s3, glusterfs, fuse, s3ql

I am trying to test run [Gluster](http://gluster.org/) with a volume consisting of two local bricks, the first being a plain directory and the second being a [s3ql](http://code.google.com/p/s3ql/) based mount.

Having just the plain directory as a unique brick *works fine*.

Having just the s3ql mount as a brick *does not work*:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root 4096 May 13 19:57 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root root 4096 May 13 18:25 ..
d??????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? gluster_testdir
```

Having both bricks added only the space of the first brick is showed as available, plus nothing can be written or read from the volume.

I am not sure if it does not work because Gluster is trying to re-mount (mount an existing non-local mount) the s3ql mount or because Gluster does not see the s3ql mount as a "real" directory even though it should.

Any hints?

Comment: s3backer actually works fine as a gluster brick. But why not s3ql?

Comment: I think it may be the filesystem type: s3backer's loop device is recognised as ext4 while s3ql as another fuse system (fuse.s3ql).